# How can I speed up putting on makeup?

Tags: makeup

I would like to be able to get ready faster in the mornings, and the way that I think I could speed up the process is spending less time doing my make up.

*What I have tried:*

I have tried skipping using liquid foundation and instead using powder, but it doesn't have the same effect - the powder didn't cover my face as well as the liquid foundation. I found that it didn't achieve a natural look. I use [this](https://maxfactor.co.uk/make-up-products/face/foundation/max-factor-colour-adapt-foundation) foundation normally, and I tried [this](https://maxfactor.co.uk/make-up-products/face/foundation/max-factor-miracle-touch-foundation) one.

I don't want to buy a different brand, because I don't want the expense or the getting used to. I find that the Max Factor works well for me.

I had a look at [this site](http://makeup.allwomenstalk.com/ways-to-apply-makeup-faster) but the tips didn't really help me. For example, *"If you do have a few extra moments, why not just do a small swipe of eyeshadow?"*, is just saying to do something that needs more time...

---

How can I continue to use everything I do (mascara, eyeshadow, lipgloss/stick, foundation, blusher and concealer) but apply it faster?

[image]

*[elkevonfreudenberg.com](http://www.elkevonfreudenberg.com/blog/2008/07/makeup-quick-trick/)*

Comment: What effect were you getting when you switched between liquid foundation and powder?

Answer (score 3):

How long does it take you to do your makeup? I'm not sure about the rest of your routine, but for foundation, I also use liquid and I found it's quicker (and looks better) if I apply lotion first.

For your lipgloss, maybe you could get tinted lip balm or something and you could casually apply it in class or work.

Also, I'm sure you look beautiful without makeup anyway, so maybe you could get rid of some of the stuff you use :)